# Clicking 'Submit' on form closes modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, contact-form

I have a modal window that allows users to submit a form as one of the call-to-actions. However, clicking 'Submit' closes the modal window but I do not want it to. [Here is the page: infowest.com/residential-internet](https://www.infowest.com/residential-internet).

To activate the modal window, the user clicks the yellow-orange "Get started" button on any of the "cards" of Internet options. Then to fill out and submit a form, the user clicks the "Request a callback" button. Actually, come to find, clicking ANYWHERE accept the "Request a callback" button closes the modal window, not just clicking the 'Submit' button.

I tried using this code:

```
if ( $(event.target).is('.modal-window-content') ) {
    return false;
}
if ( $(event.target).is('input') ) {
    return false;
}
```

to keep the modal from closing, which worked but didn't allow the form to submit or even try to submit. The form uses Ajax. It is the WP Contact Form 7 plugin.

I am using jQuery that I'm just making up as I go but I've never really been taught jQuery so I'm assuming I'm making errors in the js code. Here is my code:

```
var pagePosition;
$('.js--activate-cta-modal').click(function() {
  if ( (!$(this).hasClass('.active')) && (!$('body').hasClass('modal-active')) ) {
    pagePosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.cta-modal-window').css( "margin-top", pagePosition );
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('body').addClass("modal-active");
    $('body').css( "top", -pagePosition );
    return false;
  }

  if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-active')
    $('body').css( "top", "0" );
    $('body').scrollTop(pagePosition);
  }
});
$('.js--activate-cta-modal').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.modal-overlay').click(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('modal-active');
  $('.js--activate-cta-modal').removeClass('active');
  $('body').css( "top", "0" );
  $('body').scrollTop(pagePosition);
});
$('.cta-modal-window').click(function() {
  // if ( $(event.target).is('.modal-window-content') ) {
  //   return false;
  // }
  // if ( $(event.target).is('input') ) {
  //   return false;
  // }
  $('body').removeClass('modal-active');
  $('.js--activate-cta-modal').removeClass('active');
  $('body').css( "top", "0" );
  $('body').scrollTop(pagePosition);
});
$('.close-modal-window').click(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('modal-active');
  $('.js--activate-cta-modal').removeClass('active');
  $('body').css( "top", "0" );
  $('body').scrollTop(pagePosition);
});
```

I greatly appreciate any and all help! Thank you!

Comment: I guess I failed to mention that it is very important to me that the outer area that is darkened by the modal overlay can be clicked in order to close the window. That's why I've added that bit of code. Removing that does solve the problem of almost every click closing the modal window. I'm trying to see how to keep both UX features functioning the way I need them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important not to confuse [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) and [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), and to understand exactly what they do.

[`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) will prevent events from bubbling up through the `DOM`. Normally if you click on an element its event will attempt to fire, and then the parent element will attempt to fire its version of the event, and so on up the tree. This is used to contain events to a certain level on the `DOM`.

[`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) stops the default action that elements might have from triggering. The most common one is using this on a `form` to stop it from submitting. This is used to cancel out the default behavior of elements with certain events.

Here is an example of a common modal staging technique. http://codepen.io/Oka/pen/xGKJVJ

(If you're new to CodePen, click the eyeballs to view any compiled code. I've used Jade and SCSS here. The page is also running [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/))

With this technique we only need one [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to stop similar events from bubbling up from the modal to its container. Clicking anywhere on the modal's container will close the modal, and so will the small close button. You can expand this to suit your needs, the key is the modal should never bubble to its container.

JS

```
  var open = $('.modal-open'),
      close = $('.modal-close'),
      modal = $('.modal'),
      container = $('.modal-container');

  function openModal (e) {
    container.addClass('active');
  }

  function closeModal (e) {
    container.removeClass('active');
  }

  open.on('mouseup', openModal);

  close.on('mouseup', closeModal);
  container.on('mouseup', closeModal);

  modal.on('mouseup', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

(Keep in mind some of this stuff is IE9+. Make sure to check browser compatibility if you have legacy needs.)

Answer (score 0):

I now understand a little more of what

```
$('element').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

is for. This is used to *not* perform the click function of the targeted element. I'll need to do some more reading on this but I solved the issue by using this code to target the `div.modal-window-content`.